# Highcharts 8.0.4 is missing some x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have one JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xdkhs18p/

```
Dummy code section to post question.
```

when I increase the width of frame where chart is drawn to around 1100px and then run the fiddle I can see some of the initial x-axis labels are missing.

JSFIddle with 7.2.1 highchart https://jsfiddle.net/kamaldeka/zntm7epg/6/
This fiddle show the x-axis label correctly.

one can see the difference in the x-axis labels in both the fiddles

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kamal Deka, All x-axis labels are displayed with 1100px width: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zf6n4dgj/

Comment: @ppotaczek I assume it is UTC problem I am at UTC+5:30 and you can see the labels as I have updated the question with image.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zf6n4dgj/2/ Looks like a bug, you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Highcharts 8.0.4
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13430